# How to open camera if my device is locked?

Tags: android, camera, lockscreen

I developed an app which is for device lock, like normal lock apps.
Now I want to open the camera like android default lock screen open, without unlocking the device.
I tried a lot I search a lot but I won't get any possible solution.

Please help me if you have any solution.

Answer (score 0):

If your device is locked by the pattern you can't open camera directly, instead you unlock and open camera by using this snippet.

```
KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    if (km.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode()) {
        Window win = Activity.getWindow();
        win.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
        win.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
        win.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
    }
```

Where `KeyguardManager` will check if the device is locked or not.
Also, you can visit this link for more information about open `Camera` or capture photo in a locked device.